# How to avoid repeating a long list of parameters/argument in function calls, and have them all defined in one place?

Tags: javascript

I have the following (example pseudocode) class:

```
    class Whatever {
    
      constructor(param1, param2, ... , param15) {
        
        this.someLongInitialTask1(param1, param2, ... , param15);
        
        this.someLongInitialTask2(param1, param2, ... , param15);
   
        // some other operations

      }
    

      someLongInitialTask1(param1, param2, ..., param15) {
         //here some operation to be performed only at inizialization
      }


      someLongInitialTask2(param1, param2, ..., param15) {
         //here some operation to be performed only at inizialization
      }

  }
```

I would like to be able to specify in my code the list of parameters/arguments `param1, param2, ..., param15` only in 1 place, instead of repeating them every time I need them. The reason is to make more robust and maintainable code and avoid forgetting to change the parameters in the various multiple calls.

How is it possible to do that?

I do not want these parameters to be some field/property of the class because they are useful only when the class is initially instantiated and there is no need to "memorize" them within the object (no need to assign them to fields of the object).

Comment: You have too many parameters (see e.g. https://refactoring.guru/smells/long-parameter-list). Maybe they should be in one object/array, or several? Maybe they should be varargs `...params` (which would pack them into an array)?

Comment: why would one have 100 parameters?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you. That was just some example pseudocode. I do not have actually 100 params, but it was just to convey the idea of some long list (like 10 or so, anyway uncomfortable to maintain).

Comment: ok I see the metaphor was not clear. I changed the example to 15 to avoid diverting the discussion   :-)

Comment: If it's "uncomfortable to maintain" it's into the category of needing refactoring (15 and 100 are both more than the 3-4 generally recommended). A more representative example might help people make more concrete suggestions.

Comment: Pass in an object instead? There is nothing you can do really to make named parameters that you can reuse in place to place. Maybe a more concrete example could shed light on your actual problem.

Comment: @ epascarello Yes I was looking for something in that direction. Imagine having some 10-20 arguments and being in the middle of developing something: it's just handy to have just 1 place to edit.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well in my case I am defining some complex 3D object and I need to pass several parameters to define its "initial" state. But I do not need to memorize those. I just need to pass them along in a chain of calls in the constructor for initial setup.

Comment: I mean [edit] the question to give an actual example of your use case. If they're all related parameters describing something, and their relative positions have no meaning, an object is the best fit. I'm not sure what you mean by "memorize" - [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean they do not need to be assigned to fields within the class, because they are useful only when the object is created, and no more (initial state of a solid 3D object).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use spread operator [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax for that:

```
class Whatever {

  constructor() {
    this.someLongInitialTask(...arguments);
  }
```

Comment: Only problem with this is if you are a developer coming to use this, would you know what to pass in. I hope there is good documentation on usage. :)

Comment: @epascarello Well, that is not what OP is asking for. And I agree that constructor and following functions are doing too much or these parameters should be as associative array.

Comment: @ Justinas ok so it seems you are suggesting to just create an associative array describing the initial state of my object, that is containing all the parameters I need.

Comment: Yes, that's how you usually handle configuration values: `var config = $.extend(defaultConfig, userConfig)`

Answer (score 3):

Having lots of parameters is something I tend to avoid these days (much prefer object destructured params) but if you just want to pass args down, you can use the spread syntax.

```js
class Whatever {
  constructor(...params) {
    this.someLongInitialTask(...params);
  }

  someLongInitialTask(...params) {
    const [param1] = params;
    console.log(param1);
    this.someLongInitialTask2(...params);
  }
  
  someLongInitialTask2(...params) {
    const [param1, param2, param3] = params;
    console.log(param1, param2, param3);
  }
}

new Whatever(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Thank you. I like the passing down with this operator, but this way I still need to repeat the argument list in the various calls someLongInitialTask1, someLongInitialTask2, ... is that right ? Is there a way to specify it only once ?

Comment: You can do the same for `someLongInitialTask2` etc.  And if you still want to have access ass `param1, param2`, you could then destructure this too.  I've update my answer to show this,  for example someLongInitialTask is only interested in param1  so I only destructure this, but pass all params onto someLongInitialTask2..